# Script error with loading jQuery in IWebBrowser2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iwebbrowser2

The following error shows up when I load a page that uses jQuery in my iWebView. 
I checked if the JS files have any errors, but they all seem fine.
Any clues anyone?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Vasa, the latest 1.x version is 1.11.1:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

You may want to try pointing to that to see if the upgrade has fixed your script error. Also, using the non-minified version for development may give you more detail to line and character.

Comment: That did not fix it unfortunately :( Wondering why it shows error on line 0. If I am not wrong in an minified version it should atleast show line 1.

Comment: Vasa, can you post the line you are using to call jquery? Or is it simply in loading jquery?

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Is that where it's throwing the error or is it during another call that references jquery?